# Selecting one item from duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL query that checks the table and gives me any duplicates found.  What I need to do is select only one of those, preferably the same one every time.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(t.Value) AS Count,
    t.Code
FROM dbo.Table t
GROUP BY t.Code, t.Value
HAVING COUNT(t.Value) > 1
```

It returns me results as follows:

```
Count   Code
2   Duplicate_1
2   Duplicate_2
2   Duplicate_3
```

Each one of those have their own `ID`, I am trying to figure out how to grab just a single `ID` or the `top 1 id` but have not found a working solution as of yet.

I just need the `ID` one from each `Code` so I can then later delete it.

Here is how the table looks.  Ideally there should be one row for ever `Code` but somehow duplicates are happening.

```
id    Value Code
1    3  Duplicate_3
2    63 Im_Not_A_Dup
3    1  Duplicate_1
4    2  Duplicate_2
5    2  Duplicate_2
6    64 Im_Not_A_Dup
7    1  Duplicate_1
8    65 Im_Not_A_Dup
9    66 Im_Not_A_Dup
10   3  Duplicate_3
```

Expected Result:

```
id  Type_Code
3   Duplicate_1
4   Duplicate_2
1   Duplicate_3
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the layout of the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added the data I think you were asking for.

Comment: @D-Shih I added the expected result as requested.

Comment: Your initial question is not consistent with your updated question.  You have `id` in the `group by` initially, implying that the ids are duplicated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff My apologies that was because I was copying the original code from sql and simplifying it here.  The Id's are not duplicated, the Id is a primary key.  The .Id check was for another column that I named incorrectly when simplifying it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your sample data and expected result, you can use`MIN` function to get `ID` and use `where` clause to exclude `code = 'Im_Not_A_Dup'`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  id  INT,
  Code VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,'Duplicate_3');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,'Im_Not_A_Dup');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3,'Duplicate_1');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4,'Duplicate_2');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (5,'Duplicate_2');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (6,'Im_Not_A_Dup');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (7,'Duplicate_1');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (8,'Im_Not_A_Dup');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (9,'Im_Not_A_Dup');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (10,'Duplicate_3');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT MIN(t.Id) Id,
        t.Code
FROM  t
WHERE Code <> 'Im_Not_A_Dup'
GROUP BY t.Code
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/202a50/2/0)**:

```
| Id |        Code |
|----|-------------|
|  3 | Duplicate_1 |
|  4 | Duplicate_2 |
|  1 | Duplicate_3 |
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete duplicates in SQL Server, then use an updatable CTE and `row_number()`:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by code, id order by code) as seqnum
      from dbo.table t
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

You can replace the `order by code` with a more deterministic sequencing.  For instance, if you have a `createAt` column, you could delete all but the oldest or most recent.